# Input userform values during run time, in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, userform

[image]I am trying to add values to an array via a userform. The array is big, so I only change values at certain indices. I can add the first set of values easily, but I want to do that potentially more than once. I want to achieve the same outcome that I could with a while loop on an inputBox. But the inputBox is inefficient because I have multiple column values that are added row by row. See example code below

```
If chkBoxTT.Value Then
    r = FindIndex(someArray, txtBoxID.Value)
    Do
        For j = 1 To 5
            y = "txtBox" & j
            Set contr = Controls(y)
            arr(r, j) = CDbl(contr.Value) / 100
        Next j
        'I want to show the form and input new values as long as below condition is true
    Loop While chkBoxDone.Value = False
End If
```

Comment: Can you include some physical explaination? A picture of how this would look, and how your desired result would look like?

Comment: So you want to refresh the form once the user presses `Add Values` button and capture the values again in the array? What happens when you try to do that with current code?

Comment: I added the picture of part of the form. The code is under the button labelled "most of the code is here". the code I provided is a portion of the code under that button. During run time, I want to be able to add more values by typing them in the textboxes from the form using the button add values, and click done once done.

Comment: Hi Zac, Yes, I want to use the button to add values more than once, and then click done to continue running the code. When I use the add Values button, it does not see the array, which is under a different button, labeled (Most of the code is here).

Comment: If your array is just used in the form, declare it at the top of your form code and then it will be visible to all methods of your form. I suspect your issue is that you have declared your array in the method **most of the code is here** and it's not visible to other methods

Comment: Okay,,,I can do that. But I will still have the problem. After clicking add Values, how do I make the code to allow me to enter new values and add them. with inputBox, I can say while values entered is not -1/no keep asking for more values. I want a similar approach but using the form.